# How come a user with 1 rep has been able to comment following a question he does not own?

Tags: discussion, comments, new-users

I have been reading the contributions following [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/169771/is-html5-input-pattern-validation-sufficient-or-even-relevant-for-client-side)  when I noticed [a user](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/159422/dwilliss) has posted [a comment](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/169771/is-html5-input-pattern-validation-sufficient-or-even-relevant-for-client-side/169772#comment324095_169772) below one of the existing answers.

I am wondering how come the user has been able to comment when his reputation is only 1. Normally, we can comment only if we have at least 50 reputation (if the post is not ours, as in this case). So how did this happen?

Comment: Most likely they left an answer which was converted into a comment.

Comment: Seems like a site-specific question? I know it happens everywhere but the mods on InfoSec are more likely to be able to answer this than the normal users here.

Comment: @Catija _"Seems like a site-specific question?"_ No, that applies everywhere.

Comment: That's a plausible explanation except for the whole "trivial answer w/ link" requirement which doesn't exist here, @ale. As bluefeet noted, this was an explicit moderator action.

Comment: @shog9: All of the other similar questions I found were closed as duplicates of that one.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I spent a few minutes looking for a better target, albeit one that's considerably less obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They originally posted an answer which was converted to a comment by a moderator on the site. The original answer has just been deleted.

Mods have the ability to manually convert answers to comments.

Comment: you can mention the auto conversion too for internal link only answers